# PHPExcel: is it necessary to getSheet once you have an object?

Tags: phpexcel

Ok so PHPExcel loads the file into its objectReader

```
// 1. Load file

    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($this->inputFileName);
    $this->LogMsg("FileType identified as :".$inputFileType, "O", $opLog);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $this->LogMsg("Reader Created successfully", "O", $opLog);
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);  // if set to read only, it will ignore styling and data validation
    $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($this->sheetname);
    $objReader= $objReader->setReadFilter($filterSubset);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($this->inputFileName);
    echo ("File Loaded <br>");
```

Suppose the data is loaded into object. Now after that, in order to access data, (correct me if I'm wrong) you would normally load the worksheet. Either with or without filters. That's about the only thing documentation tells you how to do (and I've read the developer and user docs).

```
$worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
```

After that, you can transform $worksheet into an array, and you can pretty much work with data in it.  Thing is though that for big files, the getSheet method is the one that takes the most time (In my case, 5seconds for a 9Mb excel file).

I was wondering whether loading worksheet is even necessary. What does $objPHPExcel contain once the file is loaded? var_dumping it doesn't enlighten me much because it seems to have a bunch of protected properties which you can't even access from the outside. Is it anything like a $result dataset after a query? Can I work with it rather than load sheets? Are there any methods other than load() that can be used on it? Can you point me towards anything to read other than the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel file consists of many sheets as it is a [spreadsheet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreadsheet). Actually all data is stored in sheets even if there is only one sheet.

So to work with data stored in sheet you must load it in memory and make PHPExcel to analyze it. Before it there is no data available to work with.